# Intel Wireless 3165 doesn't work ( Kernel 4.4!)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, kernel

I have bought Dell Vostro with Ubuntu pre-installed. It was  14.04 LTS  and it's kernel didn't support my Intel Wireless 3165 adapter, so wifi just refused to connect.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with kernel 4.4 but it did'nt solve my problem.
Now my laptop connects to wifi, but then the whole wifi service is falls down (wifi icon not visible in status bar)

I cannot establish wired connection as well.

Hopely, you will help me. I can send all outputs of tests if needed. 
Ethernet/Wireless adapters are not soft or hard blocked and I have no wifi switcher.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you expand this "but then the whole wifi service is falls down " a bit more? When "then" it happens?

Comment: Soon after I connect to a wifi network. It shows that connection was established, still I have no Internet, then I get an error message about local domain trouble (doesn't affect anything usually) and then I get disconnected and network functions just dissapear.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually quite a few vostros, both desktop and laptop, that are certified pre-installs for 14.04 LTS, and at least two (maybe more) of those with the Intel wireless 3165 adapter.  Do you have a vostro 24-5460 desktop?  If so, the cert. notes indicate that "This system requires all available updates to be applied in order to work properly." http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201602-41486/
You may want to start there.  I'm just a newb, others might be able to give you more info about the updating process, or you may be able to research this.  It could be that " $ sudo apt-get update " would be sufficient to fix your problems.  Hope this works out!